# iOS App Clip Smart Banner validation before submission

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, apple-appclips

I want to release an update of my app with the new addition of an app clip. Apple states in their documentation

> Safari's Smart App Banner and sharing via Messages is only available when the app clip is published in the App Store.

Is there any way to verify that the app clip via smart banner will definitely work once the update is available in the store? Otherwise I basically have to **hope** that everything was set up correctly which I just refuse to believe that's the case. Did anyone do this yet and can tell me how to verify everything will work as expected?

Comment: I have the same issue. I set everything up, app-site-association and entitlements are configured, meta tag is installed, I can access the AppClip via TestFlight, but banner doesn't show up. :/

Comment: Dis you find a way ? Does Local Experience work?

Comment: Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way. I just hoped for the best :D